# In DBT, how do you check if all values in a string with delimiters are present in a list

Tags: postgresql, testing, dbt

I have a column with values like

```
a;b;c
b
c;b
d;b;a;c
```

I know if there's just one value you would do something like

```
      - name: column
        tests:
          - accepted_values:
              values: [a, b, c, d]
```

But is there a way to check if values in a column like that are only values in a specific list? I know you can break it up like `split_to_array(column, ';')` but not sure what to do afterwards. Is there anything like a python equivalent to `all(item in List1 for item in List2)` or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use array functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) combined with dbt_utils tests.

```
  - name: my_model
    tests:
      - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
          expression: "split_to_array(column, ';') <@ array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']"
```

Comment: i'm getting an error : "operator does not exist: super <@ text[]
02:00:46    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: tried doing `string_to_array` but got a similar error: "operator does not exist: text[] <@ text[]"